# Select a variable table name

Tags: sql, tablename

I am trying to write some SQL statements for queries for a Microsoft Dynamics Nav database.  I am trying to write scripts that i can easily use in different Nav databases.  The table names for each database are unique in that they always have the customer's name in the table name followed by a *$tablename.  So for example if the name of the company is ABC Company the table Rating would be 
ABC Company*$Rating and in another database for the XYZ Company it would be 
XYZ Company_$Rating.
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Your question is to board, try to rephrase it so it will be a particular problem. Also if possible it will help a lot to show some of your effort in trying to find a solution, maybe even attach some of your source code showing us where you got stuck.

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do it (though it is really clunky) using dynamic SQL.  The downside to this is that it takes a lot of code to write a simple select statement and the context of the script is not checked for errors like a normal script would be:

DECLARE @Company TABLE 
    (
    id INT IDENTITY,
    Name NVARCHAR(30)
    )

```
INSERT INTO @Company (Name)
SELECT Name FROM Company

declare @Script varchar(max) = 'select * from [[$Company$]$Customer]'
DECLARE @script2 VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @CompanyCount int = (SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM @Company)
DECLARE @Row INT = 0

DECLARE @CompanyName NVARCHAR(30)

WHILE @Row <= @CompanyCount
BEGIN
SET @Row = @Row + 1
SET @companyName = (SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM @Company WHERE id = @Row)
SET @CompanyName = REPLACE(@CompanyName, '.', '_')
SET @script2 = REPLACE(@script, '[$Company$]', @CompanyName)    
EXEC (@script2)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me why the table names are different since each customers tables seem to be in a different database. If you can avoid naming the tables differently for each customer, I would suggest that.

However, if you must provide these customer-centric table names, perhaps you could also create a set of views for each table with the 'base' table name e.g.

```
create view Rating as select * from ACME$Rating;
```

Then write all of your scripts using these views.

Comment: My guess is this is the way it was designed by the original programmers back in the day, and Microsoft never bothered to change it so it remains the same today.